# Add custom Timezone to `TZInfo::Timezone`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, tzinfo

My Rails application validates timezones (and finds offsets) by using the list of timezone names in `TZInfo::Timezone.all_identifiers`.

I am able to pull up timezones that have an `:00` GMT offset without problems:

```
irb(main):008:0> TZInfo::Timezone.get("Etc/GMT+1")
=> #<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Etc/GMT+1>
```

But when attempting to pull up `Etc/` timezones with a `:30` offset, I receive the following runtime exception:

```
irb(main):012:0> TZInfo::Timezone.get("Etc/GMT+5:30")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):12
TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier (Invalid identifier)
```

I am specifically looking for `Indian/Delhi` or `Etc/GMT+5:30`.

**How do I add a custom timezone name / offset to the list of sources in the `tzinfo` gem?**

Comment: The IANA Time Zone Database (and therefore TZInfo) time zone for the entire of India is Asia/Kolkata. Using Etc fixed offset zones is generally not a good idea because they don't reflect daylight savings (although not currently a problem for India) and won't adjust following political changes. Do you actually need to add a new time zone, or would mapping to the Asia/Kolkata zone be preferable?